# Change visibility of a view in all items of recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a  CheckBox  in my recyclerview items with Gone visibility . I want to make it visible for all items in recyclerview when I have a longClick on one of items .so I did this :

```
    holder.faviorateVideoItemRelative.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            holder.chk_faviorateVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           // holder.chk_faviorateVideo.setChecked(!holder.chk_faviorateVideo.isChecked());
            return  true ;
        }
    });
```

but this will make CheckBox  visible just for current item . 
I even moved my code to  my ViewHolder class, but nothing changed . how can I do that without loop or redrawing of recyclerview ?
I need to do something like android's default file manager long press and selecting .
thanks in advance .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `Holder` holds only current item, that's why you see a result in this item only.

First option is just to make some boolean flag and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, in `onBindViewHolder()` just use that flag to set visibility.

Also you can try to create collection of your `CheckBoxes` or `Holders` and on long click iterate them to make checkboxes visible. As for me, it's not the worst option.

If you don't want to have a loop for that, another way I see, is to implement [Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern - on checkbox creation you should add it as a subscriber to receive visibility notification.

Also there is a good possibility to use RX here:
- on long click you emit event 
- and before you subscribe your checkboxes on that event.
It's also related to `Observer` pattern.

Comment: A flag and notifyDataSetChanged() solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: @gosev   Please help on similar issue on this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55516858/unable-to-show-imageview-in-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

You could create a boolean in your adapter that stores the information if the there was a long press or not and in your `onBindViewHolder` you check whether this is true or false and set the visibility according to it: `holder.chk_faviorateVideo.setVisibility(longPressed ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);`
Then in your click listener you toggle this variable and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: please help me in similar  question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55516858/unable-to-show-imageview-in-recyclerview