# Select All Items in a Recycler View with click on single item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I will Explain my question a little bit. There's a **checkbox** in my recycler view layout, who's is invisible at the start. When I click on one of the items of recycler view, I want the **checkbox** to be visible in all the items. I have searched the internet for too long, and can't find a workaround for my problem.

---

```
public class ViewInventoryListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewInventoryListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {

private Context context;
List<ViewAllInventoryDevicesDetails> list;
private Button assignButton;
private UserLoginResponseModel userLoginResponseModel;
private android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private FragmentActivity myContext;
private Activity activity;
private int counter = 0;
private List<String> selectedDeviceSerialNumbers;
private static CheckBox checkBox;

public ViewInventoryListAdapter(Context context, List<ViewAllInventoryDevicesDetails> list, Button assign, UserLoginResponseModel model, Activity activity ) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    this.assignButton = assign;
    this.userLoginResponseModel = model;
    this.activity =activity;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_all_inventory_listlayout_cardview,null);
    //Specifying Activity for Fragment Transaction
    activity = activity;
    myContext = (FragmentActivity) activity;
    //Iniallizing Fragment Manager
    fragmentManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
    selectedDeviceSerialNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    checkBox =  view.findViewById(R.id.view_inventory_checkbox);
    return new ViewInventoryListAdapter.ListViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ListViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Typeface iconFont = FontManager.getTypeface(context, FontManager.FONTAWESOME);
    holder.deviceSerialNumber.setText(list.get(position).getSerialNumber());
    holder.deviceType.setText(list.get(position).getDeviceType());
    FontManager.markAsIconContainer(holder.deviceIcon, iconFont);
    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

            holder.isSelected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //holder.isSelected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.isSelected.setChecked(true);

            assignButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            return false;
        }
    });
  holder.isSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          holder.isSelected.setChecked(false);
          holder.isSelected.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          //Login For Visibility For assign Button
          counter--;
          selectedDeviceSerialNumbers.remove(list.get(position).getSerialNumber());
          if(counter == 0){
              assignButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }
      }
  });

  assignButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
          if(userLoginResponseModel != null){
              bundle.putSerializable("UserModel", userLoginResponseModel);
              bundle.putSerializable("serialNumbers", (Serializable) selectedDeviceSerialNumbers);
          }
          fragment = new AssingSelectedDevicesFragment();
          fragment.setArguments(bundle);
          fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                  .replace(R.id.flContent, fragment)
                  .commit();
      }
  });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView deviceType, deviceSerialNumber, deviceIcon;
    private CheckBox isSelected;

    public ListViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        deviceType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_inventory_deviceType_textview);
        deviceSerialNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_inventory_serialNumber_textview);
        deviceIcon         = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_inventory_image_textview);
        isSelected         = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_inventory_checkbox);
    }

    }

 }
```

---

This is my **OnBindViewHolder** Text. I can change the checkbox visibility by clicking on item individually. I just want it to change for all items on the single click. Just Like the Contact list in our Mobile. you just long press on item and checkboxes appear in all of the items. Any help would be appreciated.
Best Regards

Comment: Post the entire Adapter code please.

Comment: Wait i will do so, in a moment

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท no it won't apply to all items. It will apply only the the holder whose itemView was long-pressed.

Comment: I have edited my question with whole adapter code

Comment: can you please have a look @TheWanderer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change visibility of a view in all items of recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44996189/change-visibility-of-a-view-in-all-items-of-recyclerview)

Comment: First option is just to make some boolean flag and call notifyDataSetChanged(), in onBindViewHolder() just use that flag to set visibility.. Can Some exxplain @ʍѳђઽ૯ท

Comment: @HashirSaeed check my answer.

Comment: Thanks alot guys! i just solved the problem. @ʍѳђઽ૯ท. Thanks for responding. I searched stackoverflow for infinity, just coudn't find the right awnser. Thanks again

Comment: @HashirSaeed Happy to hear that. TheWanderer's answer was helpful and complete tho. Otherwise, if you figured it in another way, you may wanna paste it here and accept your own answer after that. This helps the community, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I do things like this:

Add a new field to your `ViewAllInventoryDevicesDetails` class:

```
public boolean showCheckbox = false;
```

Add some helper methods to your adapter:

```
private void showAllBoxes() {
    for (ViewAllInventoryDevicesDetails item : list) {
        item.showCheckbox = true;
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void hideAllBoxes() {
    for (ViewAllInventoryDevicesDetails item : list) {
        item.showCheckbox = false;
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then, in your `onBindViewHolder()` method, use that flag:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ListViewHolder holder, final int position) {
     ViewAllInventoryDevicesDetails item = list.get(position);
     holder.isSelected.setVisibility(item.showCheckbox ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```

You'll simply need to call `showAllBoxes()` when you want to show them all and `hideAllBoxes()` to hide them again.

Comment: Thanks Alot Mate! I just use boolean flag logic!. your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add one boolean variable in `ViewAllInventoryDevicesDetails class` to check is item selected or not and the `checkbox` selected or not **boolean isCheckSelected= false;** // Default value will be false because in starting no value has selected.

Here I modified you code:

```
public class ViewInventoryListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewInventoryListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    List<ViewAllInventoryDevicesDetails> list;
    private Button assignButton;
    private UserLoginResponseModel userLoginResponseModel;
    private android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private FragmentActivity myContext;
    private Activity activity;
    private int counter = 0;
    private List<String> selectedDeviceSerialNumbers;
    private static CheckBox checkBox;
    private int selectedItem = -1; // -1 due to first time nothing selected


    public ViewInventoryListAdapter(Context context, List<ViewAllInventoryDevicesDetails> list, Button assign, UserLoginResponseModel model, Activity activity) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.assignButton = assign;
        this.userLoginResponseModel = model;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_all_inventory_listlayout_cardview, null);
        //Specifying Activity for Fragment Transaction
        activity = activity;
        myContext = (FragmentActivity) activity;
        //Iniallizing Fragment Manager
        fragmentManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
        selectedDeviceSerialNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.view_inventory_checkbox);
        return new ViewInventoryListAdapter.ListViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ListViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Typeface iconFont = FontManager.getTypeface(context, FontManager.FONTAWESOME);
        holder.deviceSerialNumber.setText(list.get(position).getSerialNumber());
        holder.deviceType.setText(list.get(position).getDeviceType());
        FontManager.markAsIconContainer(holder.deviceIcon, iconFont);

        if (selectedItem != -1 && selectedItem == position) {
            holder.isSelected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //holder.isSelected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            assignButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.isSelected.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            assignButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (selectedDeviceSerialNumbers.get(position).getCheckSelected()) {
            holder.isSelected.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            holder.isSelected.setChecked(true);
        }


        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                if (selectedItem != -1) {
                    selectedItem = position;
                    showAllBoxes();
                } else {
                    selectedItem = -1;
                    hideAllBoxes();
                }


                return false;
            }
        });
        holder.isSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectedDeviceSerialNumbers.get(position).setCheckSelected(!selectedDeviceSerialNumbers.get(position).getCheckSelected());
            notifyDataSetChanged(); 
            }
        });

        assignButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                if (userLoginResponseModel != null) {
                    bundle.putSerializable("UserModel", userLoginResponseModel);
                    bundle.putSerializable("serialNumbers", (Serializable) selectedDeviceSerialNumbers);
                }
                fragment = new AssingSelectedDevicesFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.flContent, fragment)
                        .commit();
            }
        });

    }

    private void showAllBoxes() {
        for (ViewAllInventoryDevicesDetails item : list) {
            item.showCheckbox = true;
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void hideAllBoxes() {
        for (ViewAllInventoryDevicesDetails item : list) {
            item.showCheckbox = false;
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView deviceType, deviceSerialNumber, deviceIcon;
        private CheckBox isSelected;

        public ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            deviceType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_inventory_deviceType_textview);
            deviceSerialNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_inventory_serialNumber_textview);
            deviceIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_inventory_image_textview);
            isSelected = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_inventory_checkbox);
        }

    }
}
```

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: Thanks alot mate. It sure helped me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can also achieve this by using callback  (Interface)

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<ListItemModel> myArrayList;
    ListClicklistener listClicklistener;

    public MyListAdapter(ArrayList<ListItemModel> myArrayList, ListClicklistener listClicklistener) {
        this.myArrayList = myArrayList;
        this.listClicklistener = listClicklistener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new ListViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListViewHolder listViewHolder, int i) {
        listViewHolder.tvTitle.setText(myArrayList.get(i).title);

        if (myArrayList.get(i).isCheckBoxShow) {
            listViewHolder.chkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        listViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listClicklistener.onListItemClick();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myArrayList.size();
    }

    public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvTitle;
        CheckBox chkBox;

        public ListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            chkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chkBox);
        }
    }
}
```

Take One Interface

```
public interface ListClicklistener {
    void onListItemClick();
}
```

SetAdapter with Callback

```
myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(myArrayList, new ListClicklistener() {
            @Override
            public void onListItemClick() {
                for (int i = 0; i < myArrayList.size(); i++) {
                    myArrayList.get(i).isCheckBoxShow = true;
                }
                myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```